# CocoaPods 1.0.0b6 incorrect subspec dependents header paths when use_frameworks

Tags: cocoapods

I've got a simple simple PodFile for an empty single view app target and project named 'tf' in workspace 'ws'

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
workspace 'ws'
project 'tf/tf'

target 'tf' do
    pod 'ShareKit/Facebook', '~> 5.0.0'
    pod 'ShareKit/Tumblr', '~> 5.0.0'
end
```

Using 1.0.0b6 it chugs out:

```
MacBook-Pro:testflurry steve$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Bolts (1.7.0)
Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.24.4)
Installing PKMultipartInputStream (1.1.0)
Installing SAMTextView (0.2.2)
Installing SDWebImage (3.7.5)
Installing SSKeychain (1.2.3)
Installing ShareKit (5.0.0)
Installing UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage (1.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 8 total pods installed.
```

It won't build, an import inside sharekit fails to be found

```
#import <UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage/UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h>
```

The reason seems obvious, when you inspect ShareKit target in the pods project, the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS ends up as

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Private" 
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public"
```

I gather that ${PODS_ROOT} evaluates to ${SRCROOT} or the project dir and the headers folder is empty. Seems like I'm either missing something fundamental or something isn't right. 'little help?